# How to Delete Twilio Messaging Service

Tags: twilio

From the Twilio Console -> Messaging->Services, I see two services listed.

How do I delete one of the services?

(I tried editing the service, but don't see a delete button there.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

To delete a messaging service you need to click through to the service’s *Properties* page. The delete button is at the bottom of the page next to *Save* and *Reset*.

Apologies for the mobile screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @philnash!  I appreciate your help.